# find limit $u_{n}$ with $u_{0}\in [-1;1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$\left\{\begin{matrix}u_{0}\in [-1;1], u_{0}\neq 0 \\ u_{n+1}=2^{u_{n}}-u_{n}-1 \end{matrix}\right.$

Find limit $ u_{n}$

It is easy to figure out that $-1< u_{n}< 1$

But their graph is rather complicated
[image]

With Fermat's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)
we can find out the lowest point with $x\in [0;1]$

That all my idea. Show me your idea or your solution

Comment: Use \in instead of \epsilon

Answer (score 2):

With the graphic you immediately see that $$\lim_{n\to\infty }u_n=0.$$

Prove by induction that if $u_0<0$ then $(u_{2n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is increasing and converge to $0$ and $(u_{2n+1})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is decreasing and converge to $0$. That prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty }u_n=0.$$

If $u_0>0$ it's almost the same except that $(u_{2n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is decreasing and $(u_{2n+1})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is increasing.

Comment: And the sequence approaches zero at rate $r=1-\log2\approx0.31$ in the sense that $|u_n|=r^{n+o(n)}$.